# Django validation calling clean() even when required value missing

Tags: django, forms, validation

I am new to Django and somewhat confused regarding the validation steps during form processing. I am aware that all form field types (in my case a ModelForm) are required by default. I assumed that Django would raise a VaidationError in case a required form field was left blank *without* calling the form's clean method.

This is why I did not check if any data was set in the following `clean()` method:

```
def clean(self):
    date =  self.cleaned_data.get('date')
    time_start = self.cleaned_data.get('time_start')
    time_end = self.cleaned_data.get('time_end')
    user_type = self.cleaned_data.get('user_type')

    if Event.objects.filter(user_type=user_type, date=date, 
                            time_start__lt=time_start, 
                            time_end__gt=time_start).exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).count():
        raise forms.ValidationError("Overlapping with another event.")
```

Submitting the form while leaving all fields blank causes a

> ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value.

If I remove my `clean()` method I will get the expected `ValidationErrors` for not filling out the required fields - which is what I expected with the `clean()` method still in place.

Any idea what could cause this to happen? I would be surprised if Django does not check for required values *before* it calls clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is strange because the validation of the fields is performed before the calling of the form's `clean` method. Moreover an error raised from a field is stored in `form.my_field.errors` while the errors returned from the form's clean method are accumulated in `form.non_field_errors`.

Below is the order of the validations performed in a form:

> ```
> full_clean()
>     |
> Field clean() [field's built-in clean method]
>     |
> Form clean_*() [custom validation method for field]
>     |
> Form clean() [form's clean method]
>     |
> cleaned_data/errors
> ```

Comment: OK, thanks. But how to catch the ValidationError in each field's builtin clean method without having to run into the None types inside clean(). Do I have to check self.cleaned_data again inside clean()?

Comment: Yes. If a validationError was previously raised then the value of the field will not be in the `self.cleaned_data` dictionary. So if you want to check if a field's value is there you have to check it. E.g with `if self.cleaned_data.get('date') is not None:` ....

Comment: You can also check if an error was raised for a field in the field's clean method (e.g `def clean_date`) the same way as above `if self.cleaned_data.get('date') is not None:`

Comment: This is all explained very nicely in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean)

Comment: This is 2021, and it is still the same thing. Phew!!